# ImportError: No module named stack

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7

I have a code in python that I have been working on and it builds and runs very well on my pc (Windows). I had to run the same code on my other machine which runs ubuntu,so I had to install all the packages on prior to runing the code. The problem is I ran into this error which I couldn't figure out. The error is triggered by one of the installed packages.

```
    from qalsadi import analex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qalsadi/analex.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pyarabic.araby as araby  # basic arabic text functions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyarabic/araby.py", line 28, in <module>
    from stack import *
ImportError: No module named stack
```

I used the following command, "sudo pip install pyarabic", to install it. However, still the file stack.py doesn't exist among it's files. I searched in the folder /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyarabic. The folder contains the following: araby.py and init.py and the coresponding pyc files only. I'v insalled and uninstalled it a number of times using "pip" but still the file is not there.

Comment: Are you sure you've installed pyarabic correctly? I just did and it works fine.

Comment: Wait! Update your question, don't paste it in the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your pyarabic folder. Usually it's in `Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyarabic`.

There, there should be `stack.py`. If it doesn't exists, re-download pyarabic and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

After installation of  **pyarabic** import STACK in this manner:

```python
from pyarabic.stack import Stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## for window users

open cmd prompt and type the following to install the stack variable to python 3.x-

```sh
pip install pyarabic
```

To install and run with this code-

```py
from pyarabic.stack import Stack
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `stack` is not part of the Python Package Index so most probably it is a script you installed manually. The problem can be that the folder containing `stack.py` is not on your PYTHONPATH.

1. Open a terminal (`Ctrl+ Alt + t`) and edit the .bashrc file:

   sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
2. Add the following line:

   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/the/folder/of/your/module

where you should substitute the part after the : to the full path to the directory
where `stack.py` can be found.

I hope this helps.